# I need to print anchorPane in scenebuilder javafx

Tags: javafx-8, scenebuilder

I'm creating customized TableViews and then i need to print them the way they look exactly, so i thought about taking like a screenshot for the AnchorPane itself then printing it, so is that possible anyways ? or what should i do exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

You can place all the structures you need to print in a node for example anchorpane and then pass the anchorPane to this code,

```
FileChooser exportFileChooser = new FileChooser(); //The folder selector to save the pdf   
exportFileChooser.setInitialDirectory(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getDefaultDirectory());
exportFileChooser.setInitialFileName(fileName);
File file = new File("temp/"+fileName+".png");
exportFileChooser.showSaveDialog(owner);
file.getParentFile().mkdirs();//crete temp directory if not available
final SnapshotParameters spa = new SnapshotParameters();
spa.setTransform(javafx.scene.transform.Transform.scale(0.71, 1.1));//Scaling only if required i.e., the screenshot is unable to fit in the page
WritableImage image = node.snapshot(spa, null);//This part takes the snapshot, here node is the anchorpane you sent
BufferedImage buffImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null);
try {
 ImageIO.write(buffImage, "png", file);//Writes the snapshot to file
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```